# How to validate SQL query syntax using Javascript/jQuery or NPM library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, reactjs, npm

I have a SQL query like `select ** from table test` or any wrong SQL syntax.
Is there any Javascript or Jquery or any NPM library out there so that I can figure out the SQL query is wrong.

Any other solution will be helpful too.

Thanks,
Jeeva

Comment: Search field is like [right there](https://www.npmjs.com).

Comment: Note: SQL is not a singular thing. There are many dialects and they have astonishingly (if not maddeningly) different syntax rules.